# Обновление notification prorgress из сервиса используя Volley или OkHTTP

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-service, okhttp

При отправке файла пытаюсь обновить progress bar в статус баре через callback библиотек Volley Plus и OkHTTP, но при обновлении системный UI зависает. Я понимаю, что эти библиотеки используют основной UI поток, но как мне обновить progress bar в сервисе? Если делать все тоже самое, но в activity, то работает нормально и проблем нет (основной поток). К сожалению не могу использовать Apache Http Client. Может есть альтернативные библиотеки с поддержкой SSL и MultipartEntity?

OkHTTP

```
mUBuilder.setContentTitle("Upload image")
    .setContentText("")
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
try {
    final File file = new File(IMAGE_PATH);
    final long totalSize = file.length();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\""),
            new CountingFileRequestBody(file, "image/*", new CountingFileRequestBody.ProgressListener() {
            @Override
                                public void transferred(long num) {
                                    final float progress = (num / (float) totalSize) * 100;
                                    Log.d(TAG, "OUT THREAD: " + progress); //see in logs
                                    new Thread(
                                            new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "IN THREAD: " + progress); //not visible in the logs
                                                    mUBuilder.setProgress(100,(int) progress, false);
                                                    mNotifyManager.notify(AppSettings.SEND_DATA_NOTIF, mUBuilder.build());
                                                }
                                            }
                                    );
                                }
                            }))
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=123")
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                    }
                    mUBuilder.setContentTitle("Upload complete!");
                    mNotifyManager.notify(AppSettings.SEND_DATA_NOTIF, mUBuilder.build());
                    System.out.println(response.body().string());
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

CountingFileRequestBody.java отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/26376724/2127124

Volley Plus

```
mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NMainActivity.class);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Upload image")
                .setContentText("")
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        SimpleMultiPartRequest jsonRequest = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=123",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i(getClass().getName(), response);
                        mBuilder.setContentText("Upload image complete!");
                        mNotifyManager.notify(AppSettings.SEND_DATA_NOTIF, mBuilder.build());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), error.toString());
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return mParams;
            }

        };
        jsonRequest.addFile("images", (IMAGE_PATH);
        jsonRequest.setFixedStreamingMode(true);
        jsonRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        jsonRequest.setShouldRetryServerErrors(true);
        jsonRequest.setOnProgressListener(new Response.ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long transferredBytes, long totalSize) {
                final int percentage = (int) ((transferredBytes / ((float) totalSize)) * 100);
                mBuilder.setProgress(100, percentage, false);
                mNotifyManager.notify(AppSettings.SEND_DATA_NOTIF, mBuilder.build());
//freeze system UI
            }
        });
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        mRequestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
        mRequestQueue.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел простое решение этой проблемы!

Оригинал отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/23107289/2127124

Немного исправить код для OkHTTP:

```
@Override
public void transferred(final int progress) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mUBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, true);
            mNotifyManager.notify(AppSettings.SEND_DATA_NOTIF, mUBuilder.build());
        }
    });
}
```

CountingFileRequestBody.java

```
public class CountingFileRequestBody extends RequestBody {
    ...
    int latestPercentDone, percentDone;
    ...
    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        ...
        while ((read = source.read(sink.buffer(), SEGMENT_SIZE)) != -1) {
            total += read;
            sink.flush();
            latestPercentDone = (int) ((total / (float) file.length()) * 100);
            if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
                percentDone = latestPercentDone;
                this.listener.transferred(percentDone);
            }
        }
    }
    public interface ProgressListener {
        void transferred(int num);
    }
}
```

Код для Volley Plus:

```
jsonRequest.setOnProgressListener(new Response.ProgressListener() {
            int latestPercentDone, percentDone;
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long transferredBytes, long totalSize) {
                latestPercentDone = (int) ((transferredBytes / (float) totalSize) * 100);
                if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
                    percentDone = latestPercentDone;
                    mUBuilder.setProgress(100, percentDone, false);
                    mNotifyManager.notify(AppSettings.SEND_DATA_NOTIF, mUBuilder.build());
                }
            }
        });
```

Также можно использовать и такой код:

```
final File file = new File(event.getPath().getPath());
final long totalSize = file.length();

new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>() {
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        mUBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(AppSettings.SEND_DATA_NOTIF, mUBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            final File file = new File(event.getPath().getPath());
            final long totalSize = file.length();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=123");
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            FileBody fb = new FileBody(file);

            builder.addPart("file", fb);
            final HttpEntity yourEntity = builder.build();
            class ProgressiveEntity implements HttpEntity {
                @Override
                public void consumeContent() throws IOException {
                    yourEntity.consumeContent();
                }

                @Override
                public InputStream getContent() throws IOException,
                        IllegalStateException {
                    return yourEntity.getContent();
                }

                @Override
                public Header getContentEncoding() {
                    return yourEntity.getContentEncoding();
                }

                @Override
                public long getContentLength() {
                    return yourEntity.getContentLength();
                }

                @Override
                public Header getContentType() {
                    return yourEntity.getContentType();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isChunked() {
                    return yourEntity.isChunked();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isRepeatable() {
                    return yourEntity.isRepeatable();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isStreaming() {
                    return yourEntity.isStreaming();
                } 

                @Override
                public void writeTo(OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {

                    class ProxyOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
                        public ProxyOutputStream(OutputStream proxy) {
                            super(proxy);
                        }

                        public void write(int idx) throws IOException {
                            out.write(idx);
                        }

                        public void write(byte[] bts) throws IOException {
                            out.write(bts);
                        }

                        public void write(byte[] bts, int st, int end) throws IOException {
                            out.write(bts, st, end);
                        }

                        public void flush() throws IOException {
                            out.flush();
                        }

                        public void close() throws IOException {
                            out.close();
                        }
                    } 

                    class ProgressiveOutputStream extends ProxyOutputStream {
                        long totalSent;
                        int latestPercentDone, percentDone;

                        public ProgressiveOutputStream(OutputStream proxy) {
                            super(proxy);
                            totalSent = 0;
                        }

                        public void write(byte[] bts, int st, int end) throws IOException {

                            totalSent += end;
                            latestPercentDone = (int) ((totalSent / (float) totalSize) * 100);
                            if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
                                percentDone = latestPercentDone;
                                publishProgress(percentDone);
                            }

                            out.write(bts, st, end);
                        }
                    }

                    yourEntity.writeTo(new ProgressiveOutputStream(outstream));
                }
            }

            ProgressiveEntity myEntity = new ProgressiveEntity();

            post.setEntity(myEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}.execute();
```

Не забудьте добавить зависимости если будете использовать последний пример:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:+') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    ...
}
```

Тестировал на Android 6.0.1.